# Script to get computer name from a text file and ping them

Tags: powershell

i have are TXT File listed computer name , the computer name like follow

```
Apple
Boy
Cat
dog
.
Zoo
```

PowerShell how to import the TXT File to ping every one until end of the TXT File

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Get-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113310) cmdlet to read your text file, iterate over each line (computername) using the [ForEach-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113300) cmdlet and ping it either using the [Test-Connection](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135266) cmdlet or via cmd `ping`:

Example with `ping`:

```
Get-Content 'PATH_TO_YOUR_TXT_FILE' | ForEach-Object { ping $_ }
```

Example with `Test-Connection`:

```
Get-Content 'PATH_TO_YOUR_TXT_FILE' | ForEach-Object { Test-Connection $_ }
```